# MySQL delete according to specific date and time

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to delete rows from table according to specific date and time in
mySQL with vb.net

I have tried the following

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE_INPUT = #date_time#

DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE_INPUT = 'date_time'

DELETE FROM TABLE WHER  TABLE_INPUT = date_time
```

None of them worked

please help me

Comment: Use a prepared statement with a placeholder for the vb.net variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly like deleting based on any other value. You just specify that the parameter is the appropriate type, e.g.

```vb
Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New MySqlCommand("DELETE MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@MyColumn", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDateTime
    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Where and how you get `myDateTime` is up to you. It might, for instance, come from a `DateTimePicker` control, e.g.

```vb
Dim myDateTime = myDateTimePicker.Value
```